# java.lang.NullPointerException when using getCurrentRow in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

I am developing a mater-detail page where I can insert a new row into a details table (AstAssetReturnsVO) and set its referential key to the ID of the master table (AstAssetsVO). The code is run as part of a method call activity right before I get to the JSFF call.

For some reason I get the NullPointerException when it gets to the tagged line below and I have no idea why getCurrentRow returns a null pointer. I checked the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14022/oracle/jbo/server/ViewObjectImpl.html) and it is supposed to return the current row of the iterator corresponding to the current row of the data control.

Please let me know what I am possibly doing wrong.

Best Regards,

```
public void assetReturnInitialization(){
    getAstAssetReturnsVO().clearCache();
    getAstAssetReturnsVO().executeEmptyRowSet();
    Row row = getAstAssetReturnsVO().createRow(); 

    row.setAttribute("Stat", 99);
    row.setAttribute("AsrtDate", "1396/12/31");

    getAstAssetsVO().executeQuery();
    Row assetRow = getAstAssetsVO().getCurrentRow();    <<<<<<< ERROR OCCURS HERE
    row.setAttribute("AsetId", assetRow.getAttribute("Id"));

    getAstAssetsVO().getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Status", "Returned".toUpperCase());
    getAstAssetReturnsVO().insertRow(row);
    getAstAssetReturnsVO().setCurrentRow(row);

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Check whether `getAstAssetsVO()`  is returning `null` there.

Comment: Checked already ...not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
getAstAssetsVO().executeQuery();
Row assetRow = getAstAssetsVO().getCurrentRow();    <<<<<<< ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

This answer is specific to above two lines of code. I did not review your use case and rest of the code.

After vo.executeQuery() API, row iterator would point to one above the first row. So, you have two options. Either use vo.hasNext() to check if there is next row and loop through the records or if you just need first row, then use vo.first() to get it. Below is the sample code for later case.

```
getAstAssetsVO().executeQuery();
Row assetRow = getAstAssetsVO().first();
if (assetRow != null) {
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check it and will provide feedback asap.